upper and lower bounds for how big the moon could be whilst still letting you see the sun's corona during totality
It's often said that the reason total eclipses are possible is because altho the moon is 400 times smaller than the sun it's also 400 times closer than the Sun. But it occurs to me that the apparent size of the Moon varies.
So like the August 21, 2017 total solar eclipse had a max duration of 2.5 minutes whereas the April 8, 2024 total solar eclipse had a max duration of 4.5 minutes. This is presumably proportional to the width of the umbra. Like the larger the umbra the longer the eclipse lasts. So like if the moon was 1.5x as big as it is now then altho it'd cover up the sun and some of the corona as long as it didn't cover up all of the corona you should still be able to see at least some of the corona. And plus, some eclipses that are, right now, annular eclipses, would suddenly become total solar eclipses.
Likewise if the moon were smaller than you could still have total solar eclipses but they'd just be shorter.
So what's the upper and lower limit on the moon's size that'd still allow for coronal visibility without blocking it altogether? And what would the frequency of eclipses be for these upper and lower bounds? Like right now they say that total solar eclipses occur every 1-3 years.

The corona doesn't have a sharp cut off, and during the eclipse can be seen with the naked eye multiple-solar-diameters away from the sun.  To totally block the corona the moon would have to be very large indeed; and even if it were, you could still see almost half the corona off one side of the sun in the early stages of an eclipse.
